# Mail App keeps hanging (not crashing) on Yosemite 10.10.3

Tags: macos, mail.app, performance

Mail runs fine for a few hours, then hangs. I must force quit, then reopen. It runs fine for another few hours then crashes.

This is a fresh install of Yosemite, and I rebuilt the index and tried deleting things people suggest I delete in the library. It redownloaded all the messages already.

Here's the first bit of crash report, which is Greek to me:

```
Date/Time:       2015-06-10 19:20:29 -0700
OS Version:      10.10.3 (Build 14D136)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  21

Command:         Mail
Path:            /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
Version:         8.2 (2098)
Build Version:   1
Project Name:    Mail
Source Version:  2098000000000000
Parent:          launchd [1]
PID:             24057

Event:           hang
Duration:        3.80s (process was unresponsive for 3984 seconds before sampling)
Steps:           39 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  MacPro3,1
Active cpus:     8

Fan speed:       586 rpm

--------------------------------------------------
Timeline format: stacks are sorted chronologically
Use -i and -heavy to re-report with count sorting
--------------------------------------------------

Heaviest stack for the main thread of the target process:
  39  start + 1 (libdyld.dylib + 13769) [0x7fff8a4c45c9]
  39  NSApplicationMain + 1832 (AppKit + 13140) [0x7fff8fadd354]
  39  -[NSApplication run] + 594 (AppKit + 551923) [0x7fff8fb60bf3]
  39  -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346 (AppKit + 593768) [0x7fff8fb6af68]
  39  _DPSNextEvent + 978 (AppKit + 596411) [0x7fff8fb6b9bb]
  39  _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71 (HIToolbox + 205099) [0x7fff8c4bf12b]
  39  ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431 (HIToolbox + 205546) [0x7fff8c4bf2ea]
  39  RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235 (HIToolbox + 206191) [0x7fff8c4bf56f]
  39  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 328 (CoreFoundation + 465912) [0x7fff88299bf8]
  39  __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368 (CoreFoundation + 524416) [0x7fff882a8080]
  39  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23 (CoreFoundation + 524583) [0x7fff882a8127]
  39  CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 71 (QuartzCore + 118553) [0x7fff860fef19]
  39  CA::Transaction::commit() + 390 (QuartzCore + 58286) [0x7fff860f03ae]
  39  CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 242 (QuartzCore + 58898) [0x7fff860f0612]
  39  CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 35 (QuartzCore + 61057) [0x7fff860f0e81]
  39  CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 603 (QuartzCore + 63485) [0x7fff860f17fd]
  39  -[_NSViewBackingLayer display] + 834 (AppKit + 401702) [0x7fff8fb3c126]
  39  _NSBackingLayerDisplay + 617 (AppKit + 415019) [0x7fff8fb3f52b]
  39  CA::Layer::display_() + 1546 (QuartzCore + 70716) [0x7fff860f343c]
  39  x_blame_allocations + 81 (QuartzCore + 120468) [0x7fff860ff694]
  39  ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 59 (QuartzCore + 120535) [0x7fff860ff6d7]
  39  CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 127 (QuartzCore + 120668) [0x7fff860ff75c]
  39  __psynch_cvwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 90422) [0x7fff8293c136]
 *39  psynch_cvcontinue + 0 (pthread + 26908) [0xffffff7f80ed891c]


Process:         Mail [24057]
Path:            /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
Architecture:    x86_64
Parent:          launchd [1]
UID:             501
Sudden Term:     Dirty
Task size:       57324 pages (+4)
CPU Time:        0.074s
Note:            Unresponsive for 3984 seconds before sampling
Note:            3 idle work queue threads omitted
```

Comment: Oops, I meant it HANGS again after a few hours, not crashes ;)

Comment: Also, you probably meant 10.10.3, not 10.3.3

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same problem since updating to Yosemite. None of the advice posted on any website seems to work until I tried this and so far Mail is working fine
https://miapple.me/fixing-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite-mail-not-responding/ 
give it a shot

Comment: I experienced similar problem and it seems working also on MacOs 10.14.3

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue quite a few times and none of the solutions seemed to work very long. The issue kept on returning. 
I do think I found a cause - although I only test 4-5 times. It seems to be an issue that keychain access is open - strangely enough :) Close keychain down and mail works fine again without deleting anything

Confirmed. Might have to wait 2 mins or so before the system processes the action of closing keychain.

Answer (score 1):

My Mail.app was freezing when I tried to quit it (forcing me to force quit it) and it was also not letting me select folders (it just showed the same partial list of my email).  I tried https://miapple.me/fixing-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite-mail-not-responding/ to no avail.  Believe it or not, what finally worked was:

1. force quit Mail.app
2. turn of Airport so my Mac was disconnected from the internet
3. relaunch mail
4. quit Mail.app again (this time it worked)
5. relaunch Mail.app
6. turn Airport back on again

From that point on, Mail.app worked normally.  I think the issue was actually that it was trying to check or sync mail in one of my accounts and getting stuck.  The key step was probably #4, because if Mail.app could quit, then it was no longer caught in whatever infinite loop it was trying to do.

Incidentally, I went to Window->Connection Doctor and discovered an old SMTP server that was spinning forever.  I deleted it in Mail->Preferences->Accounts->Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP)->Edit SMTP Server List... then clicking on the bad server and clicking the [-] minus button on the left.  I don't think it was being used, but it's a good idea to not let those hang around, because Apple's interface for dealing with SMTP always made things very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

On my installation, Mail hanged whenever I tried to view the inbox. Deleting `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/` or `~/Library/Mail/` didn't help, but when I moved a single message from my inbox to another mailbox in Gmail's web interface, Mail stopped hanging. When I moved the message back to the inbox, Mail started hanging again. I don't know what about that message caused the hang though.

Answer (score -1):

I use the Mail client under OSX 10.10.3 and tend to let the system run for long stretches.

The other day, I determined that I wasn't receiving messages, and the situation deteriorated to where sent messages were sitting in the Outbox.

Solution was to **Restart** the Mac.

Comment: Thanks, Vzzdak. Alas, I restart ever day and it doesn't make a difference.